# Does containsIgnoreCase() and contains() string methods , work with a Rich Text Field?

Tags: sosl, search, richtextarea

I am working on use case, where i need to **search a keyword** on a **custom Object** containing **three Rich Text Fields**. I am using the string method containsIgnoreCase(). But even if the field contains the **keyword**, i get false in return when i do ( Rich_Text__c.containsIgnoreCase(keyword) ). Am i doing something wrong here, or is there a better way to do this ?

Note :

1. The Rich_Text__c records currently contain only texts with some HTML markups.
2. I have done a SOQL Query to search on the Custom Object

Comment: I'm not able to replicate. If I query a record to variable `obj` with a rich text field `Rich__c` whose contents are `<p><u>This is underlined.</u></p><p class="ql-indent-1">This is a keyword: <b>zebra</b>.</p>` then `obj.Rich__c.containsIgnoreCase('zebra')` returns `TRUE`. Can you post come sample code to illustrate your exact problem? It's also not clear how SOSL fits into your scenario/problem.

Comment: Sorry it was SOQL, updated my question to reflect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rich Text Fields are a tough nut to crack because of the different types of text/data that they can contain.

My suggestion is first convert this to a text field & use the string methods whatever you need

```
String Inputfield = yourObject.rich_text_field__c;

Inputfield = Inputfield.replaceAll('<[/a-zAZ0-9]*>','');
```

Comment: stripHtmlTags would be more effective, actually.

Comment: yay that's a good idea I think so

Comment: Yes, stripping the HTML , worked for me . Thanks !!